# How to wire a 220V to 12V transformer

Tags: lighting, halogen, transformer

I hope here I'll find an answer I'm looking for. Today I bought transformer from 220V to 12V, but the problem is that I have no Idea how to attached wires. Can somebody help me? here's the picture of device:

[image: the device]

Comment: According to the markings, you have a transformer that was intended to power low voltage halogen lamps.  It shows an output of 11.5 VAC on the secondary when the primary is connected to a nominal 230 VAC.  Your picture, however, does not show where the connections are made.  Can you provide more photos.

Answer (score 2):

Unscrew the cover and you'll see 2 sets of connectors/terminals. One set for primary, one set for secondary. Connect 230V to terminals marked as primary (at the top of the picture), and the second set of terminals is for 12V AC output.

Comment: Thank you very much, but maybe that's my real question, I only connect the phases, neutral is going where?

Comment: Phase AND neutral are going to primary.

Answer (score 1):

The terminals are behind the panel secured by the screw on the far left.

This device does not have the UL (Underwriters Laboratories) nor CSA (Canadian Standards Assoc.) mark.  But it does have the CE mark.   That suggests the European market.

European power is supplied in one or more 230V phases, plus a neutral.   It is 230V between a phase and neutral.

North American** power is supplied as "split-phase" with neutral in the middle.   It yields 120V between one phase and neutral... Or 240V across the two phase wires (with neutral not involved).

If you need 240V in North America, you connect two phase wires and neutral is not involved.

---

** and Colombia and Ecuador